# Combining multiple rows or results with the same title to form drop down menus with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I am picking up a project that was quit halfway through by the last guy so that I could get some more practice with PHP and databases. I have run into a problem, and I am sure it is common enough that there is a standard solution, but I am unable to find one.

The db I am working with has 4,600, so reorganizing is out of the question. It is a db of liquers for a wholesaler. Here is what the results page looks like currently:
 [image]

What I am trying to set it up so the results are returned in list form, with only one title and dropdown menus for the different sizes/prices of products that looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that there are multiple entries in the db for each product. In this example there are 3, while some have 1, and some have 2.

I am really not sure how to go about this, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the PHP syntax, but pseudocode here's what you could do:

```
allProductsReturnedFromMySQL = QueryYourDatabaseForAllProducts()
Hashtable[productId, List[productSizes]] dropDownsByProduct;
Hashtable[productId, commonProductInformation] uniqueProducts;

foreach (product in allProductsReturnedFromMySQL) {
    if product.productId not in uniqueProducts
        then add it with the product information that does not vary

    if product.productId not in dropDownsByProduct
        then add it with an empty list

    append the size of this product to the corresponding list in dropDownsByProduct
}
```

After that little bit of logic you'll have all your unique products with the common properties for each one, and a way to fetch the corresponding sizes drop down.  If you wanted to do this purely in SQL to minimize the data that's transferred, you could do something like this:

```
-- this would get you your products
select distinct id, property1, property2 from product

-- this would get you your drop downs by product
select id, size from product order by id
```

You can then build the same drop down hashtable by iterating through the second result set.

Comment: One drawback with this method is that since you're loading the entire database table into memory, it won't scale as well.  But if you have a small database or a big server then it will certainly get the job done.

Comment: True.  You could do the same thing in SQL, I'll edit to explain.

Comment: Hahaha, yep, it's really the simplest way - I was upset about that :)  You could pivot the sizes and select out a 1 or 0 if the product has that size, but that's getting a little way too complicated for this.  And I'm not sure how well pivoting would perform in MySQL.  But that'd be like the "correct" way to do it.  The problem really is that the data model is not normalized, but the question eliminated the option to refactor that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I've always approached this by altering the query so that it is sorted by product name.  Then as you iterate through the rows, check to see if the product name matches the one you just processed.  If it's the same, then this row is a different size of the same project.

Comment: The one potential problem with that is maintainability.  If someone comes along and decides to sort the products by last updated, and they don't know about your logic to get the drop downs, they'll be a little lost.  It's no big deal, but probably qualifies as technical debt.

Comment: @Milimetric: That's true, but a carefully placed comment will help there :-)  I think this is one of those problems where there will always be a drawback in some form or another.