# Combining MySQL results in PHP based on same Manufacturer

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, e-commerce

I'm i've been working on an e-commerce site www.lady-elegance.co.uk that its main product is shoes. The site works well displaying all the products within categories etc. but what I want to do is be able to have each shoe in each size as a separate product in the back end for keeping a record of stock levels.

For example: "shoe 1" in size 10 has ID 00001 and "shoe 1" in size 11 has ID 00002 and so on.

Creating each product is easy enough but what I want is to be able to display the "shoe 1" once with a drop down with each of the sizes that correspond to each of the product ID's, displaying only those size that are in stock.

Each shoe type will obviously have its own manufacturers product ID which I can use to identify the group but how to I group the same ones together.

I cant get my head around the logic for it. Could some one please help!

I have found this answer that appears similar but need some help understanding it ([Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839492/combining-multiple-rows-or-results-with-the-same-title-to-form-drop-down-menus-w))

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your database looks like, but you could do something like this:

```
function getShoes($manufacturer, $name=''){
    $manufacturer = mysqli_real_escape_string($manufacturer);
    $sql = 'SELECT id, name, size FROM shoes WHERE manufacturer = "'.$manufacturer'" AND in_stock > 0 ';
    if($name){
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($name);
        $sql .= 'AND name = "'.$name.'" ';
    }
    $sql .= 'ORDER BY name, size';
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);  //Results like this: id:00001, name:shoe1, size:10
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){       // id:00002, name:shoe1, size:11
        $rows[$row['name']][] = $row;  //group them by name (assuming you have more
    }                                  //than one shoe type per manufacturer)

    foreach($rows as $name=>$shoes){
        echo('<select name="'.$name.'">');
        foreach($shoes as $shoe){
            echo('<option value="'.$shoe['id'].'">'.$shoe['name'].' - '.$shoe['size'].'</option>');
        }
        echo('</select>');
    }
}
```

Now in your HTML, if you called this function, you would get all shoes made by the manufacturer you designate. For example, `getShoes('nike');` would get all shoes manufactured by Nike and give you select boxes for them all. You might want to make it a bit more specific, because you don't want selection options for every shoe made by Nike on a page setup for Shoe1 made by Nike. So then you could do `getShoes('nike', 'shoe1');` and that would give you only the select box for Shoe1 from Nike. Hope this helps. :)